# Running Xcode from terminal cant open javascript script (Error: Instruments cannot open files in the “TextWrangler text document” format.")

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

I'm in the process of setting up our CI environment for one of our iOS projects.  So far I have got Jenkins building and packaging the app from the command line.  I have written a automation test in Instruments (Automation) and I want to fire this from the command line/terminal.  I have followed the posts on here describing the way to do this ([Start Instruments from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410465/start-instruments-from-the-command-line) & [Can the UI Automation instrument be run from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191945/can-the-ui-automation-instrument-be-run-from-the-command-line)) so I know this is possible.

Unfortunately, when I try this I get an alert with:

"The document “AutomatedTests.js” could not be opened. Instruments cannot open files in the “TextWrangler text document” format."

Here is the command i'm using:

```
/Applications/Xcode4.6.3.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments \
-t /Applications/Xcode4.6.3.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -a "/Users/[CI USERNAME]/workspace/[IOS APP FOLDER]/IOS/build/Debug-iphoneos/[IOS APP NAME].app" \
-e UIASCRIPT /Users/[CI USERNAME]/workspace/[IOS APP FOLDER]/IOS/[FOLDER CONTAINING TEST FILE]/AutomatedTests.js
```

Comment: The issue looks like it could be due to the program you've written the tests in. It mentions Text Wrangler, is that what you wrote the tests in or is it just installed on the machine?

Comment: You most likely need to ensure your text editor is saving in plain text  (UTF-8) and not RTF or some other proprietary format

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bendyworks/bwoken

Try this instead of using xcode directly, might save you some time